# low level alternative for bpy.ops.object.data_transfer for weight copy

Tags: python, vertex-groups

I am currently using this code for transfering weights from one obect to another:

```
def copy_weights(src, tgt):

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
src.select_set(True)  # <- context object in object mode
tgt.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.data_transfer(
    use_create=True,
    vert_mapping='TOPOLOGY',
    data_type='VGROUP_WEIGHTS',
    layers_select_src='NAME',
    layers_select_dst='ALL',
    mix_mode='REPLACE')
```

However this approach needs to have the correct objects selected, the correct mode set and the correct context set.

Is there a lower level function that i can use to replace the operator call which would work independent from the context, mode and selection ?